# Creating a trigger in PhpMyAdmin causes a syntax error

Tags: mysql, database, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger that inserts into a table after a boolean field has been verified. Here is my code:

```
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS user_au_trg;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER user_au_trg
  AFTER UPDATE ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.UserNameVerified = '1'
     INSERT INTO changeLog(logId,userId,logDate, theLog) VALUES (null, new.UserId, NOW(), 'User Has Now Been Verified')
     END IF
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Whenever I try to run this, I get a syntax error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO changeLog(logId,userId,logDate, theLog) VALUES (null, new.UserId, NO' at line 6

What am I doing wrong that's causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of adjustments I would make some are just personal preference. The code is posted below. However the main issues were:

1. A malformed IF statement it needs to be -

   IF [Expression] THEN [IF TRUE] ELSE [IF FALSE].
2. Missing Terminators after the Insert statement and after ending the
   IF statement.

```html
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS user_au_trg;
    DELIMITER ;;

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER user_au_trg
      AFTER UPDATE ON users
      FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
        IF NEW.UserNameVerified = '1' THEN
         INSERT INTO changeLog(logId,userId,logDate, theLog) VALUES (null, new.UserId, NOW(), 'User Has Now Been Verified');
         END IF; 
      END ;;
    DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Are you saying my statement errors? If so, can you post the error please? If not can you highlight which part you don't understand and I will enhance my answer to clarify that point. Thanks

Comment: ah thanks i didn't see the changes at first. thank you it worked

Comment: Whats the difference between using 2 semicolon and dollar sign

Comment: There is no difference, it's just personal preference.